# Extracting certain numbers out of an XML File with PHP DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

Hey i am trying to get Frequencies out of an XML File and would like to only the numbers.

My XML File:

```
    <products>
      <product>
        <title>PT2400</title>
            <ElectricSpecifications>
               <item name="Frequency">2310 - 2485 MHz (WLAN, BLUETOOTH, ZIGBEE</item>
            </ElectricSpecifications>
      </product>
    </products>
```

I would like to get an output like this:

```
<products>
          <product>
            <title>PT2400</title>
                <ElectricSpecifications>
                   <item name="Frequency">2310, 2485 </item>
                </ElectricSpecifications>
          </product>
        </products>
```

I used this code to check if ElectricalSpecification contains any of the numbers

```
for ($i = 2000; $i < 5000; $i++){
    $value = $i;
    foreach ($xpath->query("//product/ElectricSpecifications[contains(., ' $value')]") as $item) {
        var_dump($value);
    }
}
```

I find every value but now i don't know how to save only the numbers. 
i thought about doing this with replace?

Maybe someone has an idea for me?
I'm desperate

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `textContent` of the `DOMNode`, then `explode()` values by specific strings :

```
foreach ($xpath->query("//product/ElectricSpecifications[contains(., ' $value')]") as $item) {
    list($numbers) = explode('MHz', $item->textContent);
    list($a, $b) = explode(' - ', $numbers);
    echo $a ; // 2310
    echo $b ; // 2485
    $item->nodeValue = "$a, $b" ; // save content

    // or :
    preg_match_all('~(\d+)~', $item->textContent, $matches);
    $item->nodeValue = implode(", ", $matches[0]);
}
```

Comment: that is a pretty good approach but there are XML Nodes with a different kind of words so it is pretty hard to specify all of them.

Comment: @NeunNatter I've updated my awnser using `preg_match_all()` to get numbers.